# Android Studio emulator: Failed to start monitoring emulator-5554

Tags: android-emulator, android-studio

I am forking [this](https://github.com/nutritionfactsorg/daily-dozen-android) app and trying to make some changes to it and run it. I've managed to do so on my laptop but it's painfully slow, so I am trying to set up the whole thing on my PC but I get the following error:

```
Failed to start monitoring emulator-5554
```

the emulator started and it showed the Google logo but then it closed.

This is happening on a device called: `Pixel 3a API 30 x86`.

I have another device (Pixel XL API 29) set up but there the emulator doesn't even show up and there are no errors in Android Studio.

The only resources I found matching my question is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13355942/devicemonitor-constantly-gives-the-error-failed-to-start-monitoring-emulator-55) and I've tried restarting my computer several times but it didn't work. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50086877/many-errors-while-opening-the-emulator-how-to-fix-those-errors) one but my android emulator seems to be the latest version.

All this is happening on Ubuntu 18.04.

Android Studio version is 4.1.1.

Any ideas appreciated!

EDIT 1:

Currently, I am trying to run the emulator from the command line. At first, it was complaining of another instance already running even after restarting my PC. So, I found some multinstance.lock files and deleted them. Then, it complained about permissions in the particular AVD folder so I did `chmod -R 777` the whole `avd` folder. Now, it complains that it cannot `create a vulkan instance` or something similar and that it doesn't have access to a particular file in the user's home folder, I couldn't copy the whole output cuz my PC got stuck and I had to restart it. This happened several times.

Comment: Start the [emulator from command-line](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-commandline) and check if there are any error messages.

Comment: I get the following error: ERROR: Another emulator instance is running. Please close it or run all emulators with -read-only flag. - even after restarting my computer. Very weird.

Comment: Does this answer your question: [Android Studio : emulator is already running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27014901/android-studio-emulator-is-already-running/31031889)

Comment: I saw that one but I couldn't find any .lock files in the emulator directory.

Comment: AVD uses lock directories not files. They should be located in `~/.android/avd/<avdname>.avd/`.

Comment: I found some multiinstance.lock directories/files which I removed but I get some permission errors from the emulator now.

Comment: I've added more info in my question.